# How to increase space between menu bar and widget

Tags: html, css, css-float, blogger

I have added multiple images side by side in my [blog](http://songsmp3today.blogspot.in/)

here is the code

```
<div class="images">
<figure>
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSA7XLfGrT1rMS-Ifoguz-X2igsTtMLyNG08eYR0J00YY8zJQzB8Q" style="width:200px; height:100px;"/>
    <figcaption>Itty</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSA7XLfGrT1rMS-Ifoguz-X2igsTtMLyNG08eYR0J00YY8zJQzB8Q" style="width:200px; height:100px;"/>
    <figcaption>Bitty</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2mrch37.jpg" style="width:200px; height:100px;"/>
    <figcaption>Kitty</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2mrch37.jpg" style="width:200px; height:100px;" />
    <figcaption>Commiteh</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is the css code. I added html and css in same widget by choosing html/javascript external widget in blogger by add widget option and i added that gadget below the menu bar and pages. Iam not able to know the adding of space between the menu bar and this widget. This is the orginal template as it looks In this [site](http://videos2015z.blogspot.in/)

```
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 1em 1em 0;

}

figcaption {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;

}
```

Comment: By the menu bar do you mean the green top navigation bar?

Comment: yes ur right like this http://videos2015z.blogspot.in/ the images should be display after the white and green menu bars.. in this http://songsmp3today.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change your widget order of `<div id="HTML3">` and put it after `<div id="navbar2-mid">`.

And also put a `<div class="clear">` after `<div id="header-area">`.

If I understood your question correctly, this should work!

Comment: You have to put <div id="HTML3"> below <div id="navbar2-mid">, beacuse 'navbar2-mid' is the div for the green navigation bar, so you need your widget below that.

Comment: You are right ardian thanks for the image ur right i want same thing to appear

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how Blogger works with widgets, because I never used it.

But, it you can manipulate with divs however you want. Just do the steps that I told you and it'll work fine.

Comment: how did u do this then i mean in jsfiddle or where you implemented the same thing i have seen image right like it appear to me its ok can u give more clarity i mean i should modify in editor or i have added widget to the layout

Comment: I did the changes online in the Chrome Developer Tools, then I made a screenshot for you to see them.

If you can modify your widget in any editor, then copy the <div id="HTML3">, remove it from its current position and put it under the <div id="navbar2-mid">.